# Как сделать страницы

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу

И так в чем суть вопроса, мне нужно с помощью .htaccess и php сделать чтобы в адресной строке страница `www.site.ru/?page=news` была вот такой `www.site.ru/page/news`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что это лучший вариант, но работает.
Этот код в файл `.htaccess`

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page\/news$ ?page=news [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

А Ваши варианты есть?)

Мб, так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /page/? [R=301,L]
```

или

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ /page/? [R=301,L]
```